# Why don't some images show proper Fourier and Inverse spectrums?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, image-processing, fft

I am trying to develop an application for image processing.

[Here is my complete code in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BigA0l).

I have tested my application with different images from the Internet:

- [Cameraman is GIF](http://www.ele.uri.edu/~hansenj/projects/ele585/lab2/cameraman.gif).
- [Baboon is PNG](https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png).
- [Butterfly is PNG](http://www.clipartqueen.com/image-files/butterfly-wings-with-many-colors.png).
- [Pheasant is JPG](http://www.gobirding.eu/Images/Pheasants/GoldenPheasant/Golden%20Pheasant,%20near%20Abbey%20Gardens,%202-Oct-07%20(A3)%20L.JPG).

Butterfly and Pheasant are re-sized to `300`x`300`.

The following two images show **correct** Fourier and Inverse Fourier spectrum:

[image]

[image]

The following two images **do not show** the expected outcome:

[image]

[image]

***What could be the reason?***

Are there any problem with the later two images?

Do we need to use images of specific quality to test Image-processing applications?

Comment: what's the difference between those images? formats, compression,...I don't see why an image that looks right should cause problems with FFT unless your FFT can't handle certain formats properly.

Comment: Also how can we know without seeing code, we aren't mind readers, well at least I am not.

Comment: I just transformed your butterfly without any issues as expected.
I don't have any time to check your code. Just compare it to some open source code. I used ImageJ to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [code you linked to](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BigA0l) is a radix-2 FFT implementation which would work for any image with sizes that are exact powers of 2.

Incidentally, the [Cameraman](http://www.ele.uri.edu/~hansenj/projects/ele585/lab2/cameraman.gif) image is 256 x 256 (powers of 2) and the [Baboon](https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png) image is 512 x 512 (again powers of 2). The other two images, being resized to 300 x 300 are not powers of 2. After resizing those images to an exact power of 2 (for example 256 or 512), the output of `FrequencyPlot` for the brightness component of the last two images should look somewhat like the following:

**butterfly**

[image: FFT mag of butterfly brightness]

**pheasant**

[image]

A common workaround for images of other sizes is to pad the image to sizes that are exact powers of 2. Otherwise, if you must process arbitrary sized images, you should consider other 2D discrete Fourier transform (DFT) algorithms or libraries which will often support sizes that are the product of small primes. 
Note that for the purpose of validating your output, you also have option to use the direct DFT formula (though you should not expect the same performance).

Answer (score 0):

I got not time to dig through your code. Like I said in my comments you should focus on the difference between those images.

There is no reason why you should not be able to calculate the FFT of one image and fail for another. Unless you have some problem in your code that can't handle some difference between those images. If you can display them you should be able to process them.

So the first thing that catches my eye is that both images you succeed with have even dimensions while the images your algorithm produces garbage for have at least one odd dimension. I won't look into it any further as from experience I'm pretty confident that this causes your issue.

So befor you do anything else:
Take one of those images that work fine, remove one line or row and see if you get a good result. Then fix your code.